# Excel to Powerpoint Chart

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to move specific chart from excel to specific PowerPoint slides.
If i run the macro in break mode by repeatedly pressing F8 it works correct.
If i run the whole script all the charts get copied on the last specified slide.

```
  Sub Copy_Excel_to_PPT()
    Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Set PPApp = GetObject(class:="Powerpoint.Application")
    Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    PPApp.Visible = msoTrue
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ALL PERFORMANCE CHARTS").Shapes("Chart 3").Copy
    PPPres.Slides(4).Select
    PPPres.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
    Application.WAIT (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

    End sub`
```

I was expecting to work properly after i inserted the wait command but still no solution.

The command block is present 43 times going from one slide to next one with specific charts that have specific names.

Kind regards,

Comment: Not sure why it works, but I've seen it work before - try adding `DoEvents` twice just after the `.Copy` (and remove that `Application.Wait` call)

Comment: I tried the wait you suggest but it still does the same thing.I even tried placing do event after each line.`Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'PPApp.Visible = msoTrue
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ALL PERFORMANCE CHARTS").Shapes("Chart 3").Copy
DoEvents
DoEvents
PPPres.Slides(4).Select
DoEvents
DoEvents
PPPres.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
DoEvents
DoEvents
DoEvents` . It just loops through the whole process and afterwards past everything to the last sheet. Is there any other paste modality that keeps chart formatting colors ?

Comment: Have you tried using the themes?  You can set the same themes to Excel and Powerpoint so that the charts/colors/fonts match, which should also work when pasting.  You could also create your own theme based on your Excel file, save it and reference it in your code for use in Powerpoint.  ActivePresentation.Slides(1).ApplyTheme "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Templates\MyTheme.thmx"

Comment: Like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/x93K9.png. ActivePresentation.Slides(1).ApplyTheme "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Templates\MyTheme.thmx"

Comment: I manged to make it run how it s supposed to by changing the paste command. `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ALL PERFORMANCE CHARTS").Shapes("Chart 3").Copy


PPPres.Slides(4).Select

PPPres.Slides(4).Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteShape`the initial command for paste wasent processed correctly. Thank you all for the feedback.